# Do arrays in AS2 have to be reset to the beginning when re-used?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-2

I am working with an older and undocumented set of ActionScript (AS2) and I have found that an array, when looping through it the second time, does not give the proper results. It has been a while since I used ActionScript - does the array need to be reset before the second time through another for loop?

For instance PHP has reset() which returns the array's pointer back to the first item in the array.

Comment: how are you looping through the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's is no such thing as pointers in ActionScript.
You can target each and every item in an Array by simply targeting it with myArray[index], and no pointer needs to be reset to be able to re-read it.

If your two loops produce different results, I would suggest looking into code that could change anything in it between the two loops or in the first one.
Maybe you could post it here ?

Comment: The second for loop occurs tight after the first for loop with me resetting i to 0.